# Qt Screenshot sharing app - How to select the area of a screen

Tags: qt, qt5

I am trying to code an app in Qt for capturing and then sharing the screenshots. For now my application captures the screenshot, shows a preview and saves it. I am yet to do the upload part. but before that I would like to be able to select the area of the screen of which the screenshot needs to be captured.

I tried searching and I couldn't find any helpful articles or documents in Qt. So can anyone help me?

PS: The idea is to create a similar app like lightshot and several other similar tools.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, applications like this usually do the full screen screenshot at first, then display it (covering entire screen), so the user actually sees the Qt image on the entire screen, not the real desktop. Then user can select area of the image (that shouldn't be hard to do). It is more difficult if you want be able for example to select a full single window just by clicking anywhere on it - it would require different approach.

Comment: Wow, that's an awesome tip man, thanks. So I would have to display the screenshot without any borders and let the user crop that image, right? I will definitely try that and reply here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two methods that you can use for this: -

1) Capture an image of the screen and then display that, full screen to the user, essentially allowing the user to crop the image.

2) A more commonly used method is to create a full-screen, topmost window that has no title bar and is transparent. This allows the user to drag out an area, which you can draw an outline to represent the area the user requires.

I recommend the 2nd method and creating a transparent window is simply a matter of changing the window flags, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316710/frameless-and-transparent-window-qt5).

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add opacity and a background color to these windowless QLabels? I am implementing the 2nd method. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you please ask that as a new question? It will be more widely received.

Comment: I have asked the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666152/taking-a-screenshot-from-the-selected-areaqrubberband-on-qt