# Taking a screenshot from the selected area(QRubberBand) on Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a Qt application to take screenshot from the selected area on screen. For now I am using QRubberBand to select an area of the screen. 
It works like this.

1. When the Capture Button clicked an overlay transparent widget will popup(fullscreen but without frames)
2. I am using QRubberBand to select an area on the transparent widget.

Now I have to take the screenshot of the part which I selected.

I am thinking I have to pass the dimensions I get from selecting the QRubberBand to this:

`screen->grabWindow( WId window, int x = 0, int y = 0, int width = -1, int height = -1 );`

So how do I get the info I need from the QRubberBand?
I am stuck here, so someone please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `OnMouseRelease` event you can get the rect of the  `QRubberBand` using `geometry()`. Next using the `QRect::getRect` you can extract the position of the rectangle's top-left corner to x and y, and its dimensions to width and height. :

```
const QRect & selectRect = mRubberBand->geometry();
int x, y, width, height;
selectRect.getRect(&x, &y, &width, &height);
```

Comment: Thanks. But now when I try to save the screenshot, it takes only a part of the screen not even the part which I selected using QRubberBand.