# How to capture a window automatically using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, screenshot, handle

I am using Qt to build a screenshot program.

The question is:

How to obtain the window handle below the mouse cursor?
Firstly, I created a full-screen Qt widget to display the fullscreen screenshot. When I move the mouse cursor, how to obtain the handle of window under the cursor? Of course, the full-screen Qt widget should be ignored.

I tried to use win32 API, such as `WindowFromPointEx()` by filtering the windows with `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute. However, I cannot set Qt widget as `WS_EX_LAYERED` attribute.

What should I do to obtain the handle of the window?

Comment: The answer is in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfrompoint): *"The `WindowFromPoint` function does not retrieve a handle to a **hidden or disabled** window"*.

Comment: Hi, In my screenshot app, it captures the screen and creates a full-screen window for mouse selection. How to disable this full-screen window in Qt? By the way, I need the full-screen window to respond to my mouse event and repaint. Is it possible? My idea is using WIN32 API to enumerate all windows and check if the mouse cursor is inside these window.

Comment: If you cannot hide or disable your fullscreen overlay window, [make it transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317002/1889329).

Comment: I have set the widget and its subwidget transparent. It can still respond to the mouse event. I cannot get the handle of the window below my widget.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use to add [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles) attribute for QT full screen program, and this will make Qt widget ignore keyboard or mouse events.

Then you can use `WindowFromPoint` to obtain the handle of window under the cursor.

I have tested it on the win32 desktop program and it works for me. Because I am not familiar with the use of QT, but some similar examples show that this method is feasible.

Refer [@JProgrammer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4930925/11128312),

To do this in Qt use the following code:

Include the header,

```
#if _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
#endif
```

and put the following code into the constructor.

```
#if _WIN32
    HWND hwnd = (HWND) winId();
    LONG styles = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, styles | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
#endif
```

Or refer [@mxttie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752536/11128312),

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowTransparentForInput);
```